# Conditional compilation constant not working in a .net core multitargeted sdk-style project

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, csproj, conditional-compilation, multitargeting

Here is how the conditional compilation constants were initially defined (notice multitargeting):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netcoreapp2.0;net461</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp2.0' OR '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <DefineConstants>NETCORE;</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461'">
    <DefineConstants>NETFULL;</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...

</Project>
```

**At that time `NETCORE` constant was working fine.**

```
#if NETCORE
    // Works Fine! Not gray in VS; Compiler recognizes code!
    public string Abc { get; set; }   
#endif
```

I was working with my code and my assembly didn't compile at that time.

---

After that I added additional conditional compilation constant (not editing the previous ones - `NETFULL` and `NETCORE`):

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp2.0'">
    <DefineConstants>NETCOREONLY;</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

*Overall code (assembly) still not compiling.*

And deleted this additional `NETCOREONLY` as not needed, leaving only the previous ones (`NETCORE` and `NETFULL`).

*Overall code (assembly) still not compiling.*

**The problem is that `NETCORE` stopped working like it had been before.**

I'm switching to `netcoreapp2.0` platform, but the code in

```
#if NETCORE
    // Problem; Stays gray in VS; 
    // Compiler does not understand that it shoud consume this code
    public string Abc { get; set; }   
#endif
```

is not visible to compiler. It stays gray in VS. As if it is not `netcoreapp2.0`.

The following declaration

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp2.0' OR '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <DefineConstants>NETCORE;</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

should make `NETCORE` constant work for `netcoreapp2.0`, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you only append to the `DefineConstants` property and not reset it to a new value completely:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp2.0' OR '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
  <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);NETCORE</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp2.0'">
  <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);NETCOREONLY</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```